# How to validate HTML that is in JSON values

Tags: html, json, validation

I have a collection of JSON files and some of them have as values simple HTML components. I need to be able to validate these HTMLs. I'm looking to find all the HTML values that are missing closing tags e.g. `</a>`.

Is there a way to do it programmatically?

Example:

```js
{
  "components": [
    {
      "componentAttributes": {
        "richTextValue": "<img src=\"{!contentAsset.stadium}\" style=\"object-fit:cover; height:300px; width:100%; overflow:hidden;\" />"
      },
      "componentName": "forceCommunity:htmlBlock",
      "id": "f4c08fdd-ef0d-453d-bec3-07f2a3f149f2",
      "renderPriority": "NEUTRAL",
      "renditionMap": {},
      "type": "component"
    }
  ],
  "id": "2123f43f-ff69-4e42-a662-7ba2a6b27de8",
  "regionLabel": "Column 1",
  "regionName": "1",
  "renditionMap": {},
  "type": "region"
}
```

Comment: Yes, there *exists* a way to validate HTML programatically.  For example, [libraries exist](https://html-validate.org/) to perform HTML validation.  There may also be external APIs available.  You are encouraged to make an attempt.